# Using Kaleidoscope with PhpStorm

Tags: applications, ide

I'm currently trying to get [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) to use [Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/) as a diff tool, but struggling a little. So far in Storm, I've...

- gone to Preferences
- gone to the External Diff Tools tab
- set Kaleidoscope to be used as the tool to compare files (`/Applications/Kaleidoscope.app/Contents/MacOS/Kaleidoscope`)
- also tried setting the parameters (%1 %2 %3) to no avail

When I open a file with Storm, then browse to another file in the Project tool in Storm and go Right Click -> Compare File With Editor, I get 2 separate Kaleidoscope windows each with a left-hand-side, instead of 1 window with a left and a right - any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Eventually sussed it - if anyone comes here in future, you want to install KSDiff (also available from the Kaleidoscope site), then go to the External Diff Tools tab in Storm, and set it up as:

- External Compare Tool: `/usr/local/bin/ksdiff`
- Parameters: `%1 %2`

Then open Kaleidoscope and leave it running - if you don't, nothing will happen.